# Kid's TV show with 4 boys who used coloured bricks to transform into heroes

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

The kid's TV show aired between 2007-2019. It had 4 boys who used coloured bricks to transform into heroes and fight in a different dimension. It was in anime/cartoon style. The boys would go to a shop that had a secret dimension portal in the back. They fought against two others in a pink costume and a black costume. The bricks looked like two columns of 3 1-by-1 lego bricks stacked.

Comment: I'm glad you found it! Would you mind posting that as an answer and explaining how it matches what you were looking for?

Comment: As you've found it please do not edit that into your question. Instead you can answer your own question, please do so!

Answer (score 3):

According to an edit by the original poster, this was Tenkai Knights, a 2013 Canadian-Japanese anime series.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenkai_Knights):

> Eons ago, a cube–like peaceful planet named Quarton, populated by shape–shifting living bricks called Tenkai, was ravaged by a war between two opposite factions: the Corekai Soldiers, led by the valiant and fearless Commander Beagle ("Beag"); and the Corrupted Army, led by the ruthless Lord Vilius, who desired to obtain the source of Tenkai energy for his own purposes. However, the only ones who were strong enough to defeat him were the 4 Legendary Tenkai Knights of Quarton: Bravenwolf, Tributon, Valorn and Lydendor. Facing defeat, Vilius unleashed the mighty Tenkai Dragon, who was later defeated by the 4 Knights, its fragments scattered across the planet. These heroes were never seen again, but now, a year later, Lord Vilius and the infamous Corrupted Army have returned, more powerful than ever before.
>
> Now, on planet Earth, in the year 2034, within Benham City, four young teenage boys Guren, Ceylan, Toxsa, and Chooki find an interdimensional portal to Quarton where they are chosen by Boreas of the Guardians to become the new generation of Tenkai Knights and prevent Lord Vilius and his Corrupted Army empire from taking control of both worlds.
>
> ...
>
> The Tenkai Knights toy line is produced by Spin Master under the Ionix brand of construction bricks, along with a new Pokémon line. Spin Master refers to Ionix as the next generation of construction, with "Bricks that shapeshift." Their line of products include bricks that look very similar to traditional construction bricks, but actually shapeshift and unfold into unique mini-figures. Spin Master distributes the toys in the United States and Canada while Happinet handles the distribution rights of the toys in Japan.